# Why does the copy constructor automatically cast my data into a different type?

Tags: c++

I can't figure out a decent title - please edit it if you have a better description. Hopefully someone can help me understand what is going on. I have the following code, I just compiled on linux - it works. I just don't understand how when I call `Foo` with a `const char*`, that it gets cast by (the compiler?) into my object `Test`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Test
{
public:
  Test(const char* _data = "")
  {
    int length = strlen(_data);
    internalData = new char[length+1];
    strncpy(internalData, _data, length);
    internalData[length] = '\0';
  }
  char* internalData;
};

class Bar
{
public:
  void Foo(Test _data)
  {
    std::cout << "Data: " << _data.internalData << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Bar b;
  b.Foo("This is my data");
}

// Output: Data: This is my data
```

So, I'm curious as to why/how this works - is it the compiler? runtime? Is there documentation as to why - that someone could provide a link to?

Comment: `b.Foo("This is my data");` -> `b.Foo(Test("This is my data"))`

Comment: PS why don't you use `std::string` so you don't have to worry about your memory leak.

Comment: You need to put keyword explicit before your Test constructor otherwise it can be used as conversion constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler has to look for a valid conversion from `char const*` to `Test`, so it searches for constructors from `Test` to convert the argument. This is standard behavior allowed by §12.3/1 (emphasis mine):

> Type conversions of class objects can be specified by **constructors** and by conversion functions. These conversions are called *user-defined conversions* and are used for implicit type conversions (Clause 4), for initialization (8.5), and for explicit type conversions (5.4, 5.2.9).

The implicit conversion sequence creates a temporary instance of `Test` which is then copied or moved to the parameter. This copy/move can actually be elided by the compiler by an optimization known as [*copy-elision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision).

If you want to prevent implicit conversions, you can mark your constructor `explicit`:

```
explicit Test(char const* = "");
```